# how can i make it so when i drag circle1 into circle2, square1 gets replaced with square2, which is another image file?

Tags: html, css

basically i want to make it so when i drag one image onto another image, it changes a 3rd image into another image , so i want it to be like if you drag one circle on top of another circle, the square changes from square1 to square2, which is a different color.

i tried searching it up but i found nothing really related

```
<img src="i/circle1.png">
<img src="i/circle2.png">
<img src="i/square1.png">
```

[image]

if anyone knows what i can do, any help would be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: Please show what you want to do visually to understand what you mean

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/QFq33Ie.png does this work?

Comment: guess people would rather edit my post than think of any possible solutions, the edit is still appreciated.